# Json data gets lost after import Mysql dump file to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I recently moved some client websites which were using the MySql server to our servers which are using Maria DB. The websites are using WordPress CMS.

After import, JSON fields get broken.

Is there an automatic or easy way to import MySQL dump files to Maria DB without any data loss?

I found a [blog](https://mariadb.org/making-mariadb-understand-mysql-json/) on the MariaDB website but it gives table-based solution which may not be so practical as some clients may have too many tables. And every time manual operation will be needed.

Comment: Please publish the mysql and mariadb versions

Comment: *After import, JSON fields get broken.* Does MySQL column type was JSON? Or it was some TEXt but stores JSON value?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/ - seems clear on your options - staging seems appropriate in your case. But consider dropping mariadb which isn't fully comptible with mysql anyway. and are you using row based replication.

Comment: Those are WordPress sites and I can not predict the field types as clients are using many different plugins, and those plugins are using JSON to save data. Anyway, I decided to change my server to MySQL so as not to have headaches on moving clients' sites to our servers. I don't want to have manual work on every client's database import. I don't know my client's MySQL server version as they provide only backup files. They were using Cpanel, so I checked Cpanel's default, it is 5.7 for MySql, and my MariaDB was 10.6.

Comment: It doesn't sound as though you can stop the clients switching to mariadb...

Comment: My client is not asking for MariaDB, I was using MariaDB in my hosting environment. My clients want to move their WordPress site, and they want it to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB can be installed over a [MySQL-5.7 instances](https://monty-says.blogspot.com/2020/04/upgrading-between-major-mariadb-versions.html).

A configuration of the following will allows MySQL's JSON datatype to be accessible:

```
[mariadb]
plugin-load-add=type_mysql_json
```

Or [alternately](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_json/#installing):

```
install soname 'type_mysql_json';
```

Comment: Will this automatically solve JSON problems if we import a MySQL dump to our MariaDB server?

Comment: dump or in-place upgrade. Dump and import should work regardless of this. Describe "JSON fields get broken" in your question more. JSON operator syntax also missing ([MDEV-13594](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13594))

Comment: Actually, the data is not broken but somehow WordPress can not get it properly and overwrite it. I saw this problem on two websites which were using some page builders. On one client site, they were saving video info via page builder options, and I see page builder saves all options as Json on the database. But after import, those JSON data could not be accessed by the page builder and it cleans all info when you edit the page, and it can not read the data when presenting on the website. I had a similar issue on another website too.  The data is there but when you try to edit page, it's gone.

Comment: Sounds like some SQL compatibility. Check server error logs.